# Do any programming language function calls internally call Operating system APIs?

Tags: operating-system

To list directory content in Python we use `os.listdir()`, In Java we use `Files.list(new File(dirName).toPath())`. Like this we use a lot of functions calls, eg: For Network connectivity, Print in screen, Save to files.

In all operating systems do these all language-specific function calls ultimately call OS APIs (In Windows I think it will be Win32 APIs)?

ANything we can do without call OS APIs?

Comment: Seems like the title is backwards; should be "...function calls *not* internally call..." to match the body of the question.

Comment: Try running ```strace program``` and you'll see how programs call system functions. It's automatic,  most of them, and you usually don't need something like ```os.``` to call system functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a security question, but: standard/builtin/library functions that always or sometimes don't use OS:

- basic math: min/max abs sqrt log/exp (sometimes multiple bases) sin/cos/etc. 'pow' (exponentiation) is a function call in some languages but an operator in others. Sometimes basic statistics like erf. Often a random number generator. Complex arithmetic may be library functions and/or an additional type(s) for the usual operators. Some 'special' math operations may be functions like C's div ldiv fma.
- memory management where explicit, like C malloc calloc realloc free. In Pascal both new and dispose are library routines. In Ada new is an operator but Unchecked_Deallocation is a library routine. In Fortran most memory operations are statements but move_alloc is a library function.
- bulk memory operations where needed, like C memcpy memcmp strcpy strcat strcmp str[c]spn and the 'wide' (wcs) variants. Java frequently allows array slicing as part of other routines/methods, but `System.arraycopy()` is a commonly used library function.
- data conversion/formatting/parsing: C sprintf/sscanf (and wide and va_arg versions); Java Integer.{parseInt,toString} etc. Usually includes handling of (possible) multiple character codes. Often includes or is linked to internationalization/localization (aka 'locale') functions.
- data 'collections' and operations on them: nearly everything in `java.util.*`; much of what started as STL in C++; C sort and bsearch. In Java(8+) also support functions for (object) streams.
- date-and-time operations, often including timezone handling.
- 'I/O' that doesn't really input or output: e.g. in Java `FileInputStream` uses the OS but `ByteArrayInputStream` doesn't.
- graphics processing other than actual display, such as rendering, shading, movement. Audio, image, and video encoding, decoding, and manipulation of many kinds.
- compression and cryptography: sometimes these are wholly userspace, sometimes partly or even wholly in the OS.